# Forced inline errors (testing) using Matrix and Safecracker File not working

Tags: matrix, safecracker, safecracker-file

I have a Safecracker form with a couple of Matrix fields, both of which have Safecracker File fields in them. On testing them, I've been trying to break the form by uploading files outside of the specifications set in the File Upload preference - both in pixel size, file size and file type.

Testing all situations, the file's are actually getting uploaded if they're the correct file type but larger in pixel and file size are allowed.

It doesn't allow for file uploads of a different type though, but frustratingly also doesn't display any error messages.

EE v2.5.5, Matrix v2.5.6, Safecracker File v2.1

Sample template code for the two fields below:

```
{exp:safecracker 
    channel="awaentry" 
    return="entries/nomination/URL_TITLE/success" 
    id="award-entry-form"
    class="standard-form"
    url_title="{segment_3}"
    include_jquery="no"
    author_only="yes"
    error_handling="inline"
}

{global_errors}<div class="alert">
    {error}
</div>{/global_errors}

{field_errors}<div class="alert">
    {error}
</div>{/field_errors}

<div class="field">
    <span class="label">Screen Grabs (Desktop)</span>
    <div class="formHelp">Please provide a set of screen grabs with details, that can be used for promotional purposes.</div>
    {field:website_screens}
</div>

<div class="field">
    <span class="label">Screen Grabs (Mobile)</span>
    <div class="formHelp">Please provide a set of screen grabs with details, that can be used for promotional purposes.</div>
    {field:website_screens_mobile}
</div>

<div class="formControls">
    <button type="submit" class="submit">Save Entry</button>
</div>

{/exp:safecracker}
```

Has anyone come across these problems before? A search seems to say no, well not that has been reported anyway. Changelogs for EE v2.6.1 don't mention anything specific to this problem.

Comment: Brendan,
line 732 of ft.safecracker_file.php has the error message (should there be one) commented out, so this might be a question better directed to EllisLab.